# Pop value from dictionary stored in Flask session

Tags: python, session, flask

Here is my session variable,

```
session['data'] = json.loads(request.data.decode())
print(session.pop('data', None))
```

Print looks like this:

```
{u'mark': u'all', u'chr': u'1A', u'distmin': 5, u'distmax': 10}
```

My question is, how to subset this dict,

```
print(session.pop('data["mark"]', None))
```

This is not working, this returns `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't how Python's mappings work. `data["mark"]` is a valid key. To access nested mappings, you need to specify the keys separately.

```
session['data']['mark'] = 'spam'
```

The key used for `pop` should match that for `__getitem__`. Just as you don't use `session['data["mark"]']` to access the dictionary associated with the `data` key, you wouldn't remove keys the same way. The syntax you're looking for is

```
session['data'].pop('mark', None)
```

Mark the session as modified after changing a nested object like this.  The session can only do this automatically for direct changes.

```
session.modified = True
```